# flex and bison recursion issue

Tags: parsing, recursion, bison, flex-lexer

I'm new to flex and bison and I'm trying to parse a file with flex and bison but there is an issue with one of the recursions that maybe someone can help me with, it looks a little like this:

```
details : empty | details detail ;
detail:
TOKEN
string
string
nestedDetails
integer ;
```

whereby:

```
nestedDetails : empty 
|
string
integer
integerPairs ;
```

and:

```
integerPairs : integer integer | integerPairs integer integer ;
```

My problem is this:

when parsing the file, bison goes through "nestedDetails" and never reaches the final integer call (presumably, when he finds the final integer he is looking for another integer because he thinks it is the first of a pair defined in "nestedDetails") and thus leaves me with a syntax error because the next thing he finds is not relevant for him.

Is there any clever way of letting bison know that he has actually reached the final integer, and he can move on to the next section? Preferably without having to define new tokens in flex, that has already let to some unpleasant surprises.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution, but it changes the parse tree slightly. (It's easy to recover, though. See below.)

`nestedDetails` must always be followed by an `integer` but as the question indicates, it is not clear whether an `integer` should be shifted or trigger a reduce until the token following the `integer` is encountered. So the simple solution is to delay the decision:

```
details : %empty | details detail ;
detail  : TOKEN string string nestedDetailsPlusInteger ;
nestedDetailsPlusInteger
        : integer
        | string integer integerPairs integer ;
integerPairs
        : integer integer
        | integerPairs integer integer ;
```

To recover the original parse tree, `nestedDetailsPlusInteger` needs to have a semantic value which consists of the `nestedDetails` plus an `integer`; in the action associated with `detail`, these two parts can be used to construct an appropriate object. Pseudo-code:

```
details : %empty             { $$ = make_details(); } 
        | details detail     { append_detail($1, $2); $$ = $1; }
detail  : TOKEN string string nestedDetailsPlusInteger 
                             { $$ = make_detail($1, $2, $3,
                                                $4.first, $4.second);
nestedDetailsPlusInteger
        : integer            { $$ = make_pair(NULL, $1); }
        | string integer integerPairs integer 
                             { $$ = make_pair(make_nested($1, $2, $3),
                                              $4);
```

Comment: thanks very much for that rici, it was a silly time to post the question, i can't implement the solution until monday so I'll let you know how it went then.

Comment: i gave it a try but for some unknown reason, it still didn't work. so instead of pairs of integers, i threw them all into one integer list and i'll sort them out internally when i need to. thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @TomM: In  what way didn't it work? I checked it with bison (but with `integer` and `string` being tokens), and it seems to work fine for me. (Although you're probably right that just parsing a list of integers and splitting them up at  the end of the detail production is probably easier.)